# Accessing Azure Cli from Prowershell in devops pipeline

Tags: kubernetes, devops, pipeline, credentials, azure-cli

I'm currently working on a pipeline job that requires kubernetes access through powershell.
The only issue is that I need to sign in for Az cli. For testing I'm using my personal credentials, clearly not a good definitive option. Are there any other options for Azure cli login that could be used instead?
[image]

Comment: Have you created a service principal from azure devops to azure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you are working with hosted agents, therefore, you need to configure `kube.config` on the hosted agent.

in order to do that, run `az aks get-credentials --name $(CLUSTER_NAME) --resource-group $(RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME)`. The easiest way is to use `Azure CLI` task. Be aware that this task required authorization from Azure DevOps to Azure.
More info can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

In case you are the subscription owner- select your subscription and click on `Authorize`.

[image]

[image]

When the `kube.config` configured on the hosted agent, you can run any `kubectl` command you wish (Using Powershell\Bash\CMD).

[image]

Comment: yeah, the authorization for devops for azure was an issue, I manged to login with a "service principal" credentials. It then worked perfectly