# Azure Pipeline: Could not find kubectl server version

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-pipelines, azure-aks

I have an error on my Azure AKS, when performing create imagepullsecret.

From the logs, It said Could not find kubectl server version.
Appreciate if someone can address how to fix this issue.

[image]

Comment: take a look at my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61867919/9931092

Comment: Hi Herman, Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue is related to the service connection, I have fixed it.

Comment: Great! Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could accept it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this means that you need to first pull kubernetes credentials, so you either lack permissions or there is no connection to the cluster or cluster details are wrong

Comment: `az aks get-credentials -n name -g rgname`, but you should create a proper kubernetes connection, probably and update that with valid credentials

Comment: This is on azure pipeline, I believe is already assign based on the pipeline couple days ago is fine, then today is not right

Comment: well, if it was working yesterday - maybe its just a glitch and it will go away on its own soon, or maybe aks got deleted or maybe many different things. test your kubernetes connection, try another agent pool, etc

Answer (score 0):

If "Set authorized IP ranges" is set under "Networking" in Azure Kubernetes Services, this is going to block even the Cloud Shell in Azure Portal. Azure DevOps also wont be able to connect.

So if `kubectl get nodes` times out, try looking there.